# How to prove the Divergence of cesaro mean of harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, cesaro-summable

How do you prove that the Cesàro mean of the harmonic series diverges.

I know that the harmonic serie

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k}$$ diverges,

However, I'm having trouble proving that it also diverges in the sense of Cesaro.

I have that

$$\sigma_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{m =1}^n \sum_{k =1}^m \frac{1}{k}$$

So, we can write

$$\sigma_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\sum_{m=k}^{n}1$$
and then we have
$$\sigma_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}(n+1-k)$$
but then I dont know how to continue. I thought that maybe the $\limsup_{n\geq k} \sigma(n)$ could maybe help but i'm really stuck and would appreciate any help!

Comment: Check this: [The Cesàro Mean Theorem in the infinite case](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/850682/42969) or this: [Is the Cesàro summation of a sequence divergent to infinity divergent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1836226/42969). The partial sums of the harmonic series diverge to infinity, therefore their means diverge to infinity as well.

Comment: $\sum_1^mk^{-1}$ is $\log m$ plus lower order terms. $\sum_1^n\log m$ is $n\log n$ plus lower order terms. So your $\sigma_n$ is $\log n$ plus lower order terms.